# Which tags are available in Trends?

Tags: support, trends

The [just](https://stackoverflow.blog/2017/05/09/introducing-stack-overflow-trends/) announced [Stack Overflow Trends](https://insights.stackoverflow.com/trends) gives you an overview of the tag usage in the past years.

What are the qualifications of a tag to be available in that list? For example, I tried to filter on the [office-js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/office-js) tag, but it isn't available in the list. [c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23), [c#-3.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23-3.0) and [c#-4.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23-4.0) are, but not [c#-5.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23-5.0) or higher.

It is due to age? A minimum required number of questions? A bug?

Comment: [tag:c#-4.0] seems to be in the list now but not higher

Comment: You are right. Updated @the

Comment: I don't think it's due to age. I can't see them either and I'm in my late thirties.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

From a [comment on the post](https://stackoverflow.blog/2017/05/09/introducing-stack-overflow-trends/#comment-3296613653), David Robinson clearly mentioned that only tags that have more than 2000 questions can be queried:

> Yep- only ones with at least 2000 questions on Stack Overflow, I'm afraid

Comment: Yeah, 2113 tags in the list. A fun [JSON dataset](https://cdn.sstatic.net/insights/data/month_tag_percents.json) to play with if you're bored!

Comment: @DavidG Oh, here is [a bit more detail as a CSV (6 MB)](https://gist.github.com/dgrtwo/23f016f228ef72e4abf5b2ffc25af2cd) if that helps. It's all queryable from the Stack Exchange Data Explorer too, I should put together a query if no one else does

Comment: @DavidRobinson You data scientists, always showing off your big data. :P

Answer (score 2):

@DavidRobinson also explains [why the threshold is 2000 questions](https://stackoverflow.blog/2017/05/09/introducing-stack-overflow-trends/#comment-1890):

> First reason is performance; the Trends page doesn’t make any asynchronous calls; it frontloads the per-month data (currently) 1.4 MB JSON dictionary, and shrinking the tag size limit expands that size a lot (we include about 2100 tags here, but there are 40K tags in total).
>
> Second reason is that a lot of rare tags look really crummy as line plots, due to noise between months.
>
> Third reason is it makes the auto-suggestion more useful. Try typing in “android” and you’ll see it suggests about 43 different tags. Now imagine that for almost anything you’re typing (type “node” for node.js and get nodemon, nodeclipse, nodetool, and other obscure tags), and most of the tags being uninformative when rendered. This helps point users towards the tags that are worth graphing.
>
> It’s not the only choice we could have made, but I hope these reasons help explain it!