# Stack Overflow Trends not updated

Tags: feature-request, bug, trends

Data are not updated for [Trends](https://insights.stackoverflow.com/trends) since April 2017. Shouldn't it be updated monthly?

Comment: Did someone say that? I don't recall seeing anything to that effect. Were monthly updates announced anywhere?

Comment: Then again, I don't know everything happening... Just looking for a link to where it was said/announced/promised/implied.

Comment: I think the general [announcement](https://stackoverflow.blog/2017/05/09/introducing-stack-overflow-trends/) having "we’re introducing the Stack Overflow Trends tool to _track_ [...] based on the number of Stack Overflow questions asked _per month_" (emphasis mine) might have created an expectation.

Comment: So should this be changed to a feature-request?

Comment: @Dijkgraaf Is it a [feature-request] if the feature was already announced as functional, but isn't currently working?

Comment: @Draco18s Where was that specific feature announced?

Comment: @NobodyNada Let me quote Mabi, about 3 comments up: *`I think the general announcement having "we’re introducing the Stack Overflow Trends tool to track [...] based on the number of Stack Overflow questions asked *per month*" (emphasis mine)`*

Comment: @Draco18s That just says the tool graphs the number of questions asked per month (i.e. "month" is the X-axis and "questions asked" is the Y-axis); it doesn't say anything about whether they'll update it in future months.

Comment: would be useful if it is updated regularly for sure. besides now when I enter the site, it takes time before I see the graph on the right side as well as the tags to which that graph corresponds to. (initially it gives impression  page should start empty but then suddenly a graph appears with tags on the left)

Comment: Right now it's getting close to a year since the last update. I'm here because the React 16/MIT license event is after the last data available there and I'm very interested to know if it had an effect visible in Trends.

Comment: I would love to see how fabricjs is doing.

Comment: Trends seems to be kept updated in terms of questions asked per tag. Or is this thread only referring to the tags? [This thread](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/349014/6243352) mentions that tags with < 2k questions aren't available. @AndreaBogazzi [fabricjs is there now though](https://insights.stackoverflow.com/trends?tags=fabricjs)