# Tags with less than 2,000 questions cannot be tracked with SO Trends

Tags: feature-request, trends

Currently, [Stack Overflow Trends](https://insights.stackoverflow.com/trends) only supports tags with at least 2,000 questions. ([source](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/349014/3357935)).

It would be nice if SO Trends supported less popular tags as well, as it would allow for comparisons such as [autohotkey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/autohotkey) (*2,440*) vs [autoit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/autoit) (*1,539*).

If adding support isn't possible, then I would like to see an error message added when users try to add an unsupported tag to prevent confusion. Something like "*Tags with fewer than 2,000 questions are not currently supported*".

Comment: at the time of you writing this, AutoHotKey had over 2000 questions. Why didn't it appear in the tool?

Comment: @Ooker Autohotkey appeared in the tool. I wanted to compare it to autoit, which did not appear.