# Cannot select tag "fastapi" on the Stack Overflow trends page

Tags: support, trends

I wanted to see how FastAPI is trending compared to other Python frameworks, but I don't seem to be able to select **fastapi** on the **Stack Overflow Trends** page:

[image: Me entering fastapi in tags input]

[Manually editing](https://insights.stackoverflow.com/trends?tags=django%2Cflask%2Cfastapi) the URL doesn't work either.

Am I missing something here? (Note the tag is exactly called [fastapi], no dash between.)

Comment: It used to be that only tags with 100 questions were available in SO trends, they've potentially increased this threshold but fastapi doesn't reach the new threshold?

Comment: I agree with Nick. I've tested `java.util.date` which has 302 questions and it isn't available as well.

Comment: @Nick thank you that was the actual reason https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/348998/which-tags-are-available-in-trends

Comment: That's a cool tool! I've never seen that before.

Comment: @zcoop98 yes, it is such a great piece of software